# Application deployed only in Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, infrastructure

From AWS infrastructure side sometimes the client suggests on having their whole application to be in private subnet (both fronetend and backend), so that their application is secure . Now i do understand that for an Application to be in private subnet , we cant have internet facing App Load Balancer as AWS doesnt allow it . So in this kind of scenario , how this can be handled please. I know that we can make use of VPC endpoints so that the internal traffic doesnt leave AWS network. Is there any way this can be done that i am not aware. Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not look like a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is a very broad topic and probably sits within the realms of "How do I architect a web app securely in AWS?"

As with most things, there isn't just one answer.  Below is a common approach to deploying a simple web app behind a load balancer

**Internet facing load balancer with application in private subnet**

The application can be deployed in private subnets (so instances are not assigned public IP addresses).  You can then deploy an internet facing load balancer to the public subnets which will be able to route traffic to your private subnets  (assuming your VPC route tables are configured correctly)

If the instances deployed in the private subnets need and outbound Internet comnection you can deploy a NAT Gateway (with the appropriate routes in your VPC route table of course)

In this setup your inbound traffic goes:

`Internet Gateway --> Load Balancer Node (Public Subnet) --> Target Group (Private Subnet)`

And your outbound traffic (if needed) goes:

`Instance (private subnet) --> NAT Gateway --> Internet Gateway`

**You can't have an internet facing load balancer in private subnets (Quote from your question)**

That is true, but as described above you can deploy an internet facing load balancer into public subnets and still have it route traffic to your private subnets.  Just make sure your VPC route table is setup correctly (i.e. there is a route in the route tables associated with your subnets for your VPC CIDR block)

Comment: Thanks @GreenyMcDuff That clears my doubt. I just wanted to be sure that there is no way to dsign apps if we just have our application in private subnets.